# chef automate api to get the compliance reports for all nodes not working

Tags: api, automation, chef-infra, devops, azure-devops-rest-api

I am planning to get the chef automate report(including node description, profiles,pass/fail controls) for all nodes.

So far as per the link `https://docs.chef.io/automate/api/#operation/ReportingService_ListReports` got the report for individual nodes using the automate api.

The code is

1. Retrieve report ID for single node using server fqdn.

> curl -s --insecure -H "api-token: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
> https://automate.com/api/v0/compliance/reporting/reports -d '{
> "filters": [{"type":"node_name","values":["test.com"]}]}'

2. Using above ID, extract compliance report for single node.

> curl -s --insecure -H "api-token: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
> https://automate.com/api/v0/compliance/reporting/reports/id/YYYYYYXXXXXXXXUUUUUUU
> -d {}

Can you advise about the api to extract the compliance report for all nodes instead of single node.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the *"page"* and *"per_page"* parameters in your request.

**per_page** - tells Automate how many results to include in each page of results.

**page** - which page of the result set to return

If you have 100 nodes the following should return the results for 10 of those nodes (21-30)

curl... -d {"per_page":10, "page":3}